# Should I return List or ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, interface

I find myself agreeing to return an interface instead of a concrete class.

The reason is simple, I want loose coupling.

But will there be other implications or trade offs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For types like List or ArrayList there shouldn't be any complication and you should return List promoting [code to an interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns).

You will find yourself restricted doing so, had this been from the Concurrency package like [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) and you were using methods like [addIfAbsent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html#addIfAbsent%28E%29) which is not defined in the List interface.

So, if you return ArrayList or any concrete implementation for that matter you can use API which are not defined in the contract (`List` interface), but then you are restricted in changing from a specific implementation to something else (from `ArrayList` to `LinkedList`), as everyone using your API will have to change as per your changes. It's too much to expect I think.

Answer (score 22):

It's best to return the most generic type that's appropriate for your interface.

If there's some reason why `ArrayList` is inherently appropriate for the data you're returning then you should use that. Typically `List` is fine but you might also consider using `Collection` if the returned values are inherently unordered:

[image: Diagram of Java collections hierarchy]

Answer (score 4):

The implication is that you won't be able to call methods of `ArrayList` that are not methods of the `List` interface for the objects returned.

But, if the object is an `ArrayList` you can do a cast.

Answer (score 4):

The only reason to return a concrete class could be if the caller needs to be aware of this concrete implementation or, possibly, additional interfaces on the concrete implementation. For example, in Android, you often have to use `ArrayList` because the framework does not know how to properly serialize the generic `List` interface.