# How to automatically add objects to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Ok, I'm relatively new to programming and I have a quite important question.

What I'd like to do is create a while statement that would automatically add objects to an ArrayList. Let me show you an example:

```
ArrayList<Person> Group = new ArrayList<Person>();
while (myFile.hasNextLine()) {
   Person newPerson = new Person (myFile.nextLine());
   Group.add(newPerson);
}
```

And that way it would automatically create and add new Persons to the list.
Can you please help me?

Comment: You're doing what you're asking. What's the issue here?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you already have?

Comment: what do you exactly want?? read from file and add objects or just add any objects to array??

Comment: Your question is the answer for your question.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, that's the problem with me, I figure it out while I'm asking for help.
My bad

Comment: @h.demoff, Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some of your names are correct and others are not. Be consistent!!!

Comment: @camickr thanks for your help, I'll try to fix that

Comment: @h.demoff was it just an attempt to gain some SO reputation points?

Comment: @AadityaGavandalkar haha not at all, The truth is that I didn't think that this was possible and I hadn't compiled it.

Comment: @h.demoff you should try (i.e. compile and test) before posting a question so as to save others time and effort. Unable to understand, why would anyone blindly post query on SO.

Comment: @AadityaGavandalkar yea really sorry about that, I'm very new to programming

Comment: While we are talking about best practices. You should't store and the `new ArrayList<Person>()` into an `ArrayList` but rather in a `List`. So the line `ArrayList<Person> group = new ArrayList<Person>();` would be `List<Person> group = new ArrayList<Person>();`

Comment: @Bumbolt Why should I do that ? What are the benefits ?

Comment: @h.demoff welcome to Stack Overflow! For future reference, these - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - are some good docs to read through to make sure you're asking good, efficient, well-documented questions.

Comment: @h.demoff Long story short to make it more generic. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328658/should-i-return-list-or-arraylist

Answer (score 2):

Java 8:

```
public List<Person> createGroupFor(String pathToPersonsFile) {
   Path myFilePath = Paths.get(pathToPersonsFile);
   return Files.lines(myFilePath)
               .map(Person::new)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: I don't have a java8 compiler in front of me, but I think you don't even need the `createPerson` method. You can just do `.map(Person::new)`.

Comment: I updated the answer. Thanks. I just freehanded it too. May have gone to fast :)